# How to use links (anchor tag) inside translations in Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-boot, templates, hyperlink, thymeleaf

I have below content to be shown, where "[here](https://sample.com)" needs to link.

```
Hi, your password has been changed, Click here if it is not intended.
```

What is the best way to have transations.?
Do we need to have seperate translation for "**Hi, your password has been changed, Click** " and "**if it is not intended.**"

or any other easiest way in thymeleaf?

Answer (score 0):

The proper translation of the strings which has HTML formatting inside almost impossible in the right way. What is the right way? The translated resource string should be used by Thymeleaf as *escaped text* ([th:text](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#using-thtext-and-externalizing-text)) into HTML tag using attribute ...

```
<div th:text="#{full_string_id}">Start string Link End string</div>
```

Where `full_string_id=Start string Link End string`

This particular construction is completely translatable for any international language, including RTL. As long as you starting to drop the full sentence onto the pieces to get special formatting for each piece, you will get the troubles with some of the international languages, including RTL. For example, the English sentence presented with ...

```
<span th:text="#{first_string_id}">Start string</span>
<a href="#" th:text="#{link_string_id}">Link</span>
<span th:text="#{last_string_id}">End string</span>
```

But another international language sentence may have the proper translation as `Link End string Start string`.

So there is nothing you can do? Sure you have a few solutions ...

For example, you may use *unescaped text* ([th:utext](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#more-on-texts-and-variables)) and keep your string formatting inside the resources.

```
<div th:utext="#{full_formatted_string_id}">Start string <a href="#">Link</a> End string</div>
```

Where `full_formatted_string_id=Start string <a href="#">Link</a> End string` for English, and for another international language `full_formatted_string_id=<a href="#">Link</a> End string Start string`

The best solution, from my point of view, is the most simple one: Do not put formatting into your resource strings, instead just rephrase your sentence. In this case, you still able to use *escaped text* (so, you do not compromise security), and translation on any international language will work. For example, instead of `Hi, your password has been changed, Click here if it is not intended.`, use something like `Hi, your password has been changed. if it is not intended, please click the following link:` and separate resource string for `Link title`.